# Avoid triggering Firebase functions by real-time database on special cases

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Sometimes we use the firebase functions triggered by real-time database (onCreate/onDelete/onUpdate ...) to do some logic (like counting, etc).

My question, would it be possible to avoid this trigger in some cases. Mainly, when I would like to allow a user to import a huge JSON to firebase?

Example:
a function E triggered on the creation of a new child in /examples. Normally, users add examples one by one to /examples and function E runs to do some logic. However, I would like to allow a user (from the front-end) to import 2000 children to /examples and the logic which is done by function E is possible at import time without the need for E. Then, I do not need E to be triggered for such a case where a high number of functions could be executed. (Note: I am aware of the 1000 limit)

**Update**:
based on the accepted answer, submitted my answer down.

Comment: It's possible to use a parameter, like this: if(status === 'dont') return ?

Comment: but this will trigger the function, right? so we just skip the logic and throttle the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to disable a Cloud Function programmatically without just deleting it. However this introduces an edge case where data is added to the database while the import is taking place.

A compromise would be to signal that the data you are uploading should be post-processed. Let's say you were uploading to `/examples/{pushId}`, instead of attaching the database trigger to `/examples/{pushId}`, attach it to `/examples/{pushId}/needsProcessing` (or something similar). Unfortunately this has the trade-off of not being able to make use of `change` objects for `onUpdate()` and `onWrite()`.

```js
const result = await firebase.database.ref('/examples').push({
  title: "Example 1A",
  desc: "This is an example",
  attachments: { /* ... */ },
  class: "-MTjzAKMcJzhhtxwUbFw",
  author: "johndoe1970",
  needsProcessing: true
});
```

```js
async function handleExampleProcessing(snapshot, context) {
  // do post processing if needsProcessing is truthy
  if (!snapshot.exists() || !snapshot.val()) {
    console.log('No processing needed, exiting.');
    return;
  }

  const exampleRef = admin.database().ref(change.ref.parent); // /examples/{pushId}, as admin
  const data = await exampleRef.once('value');

  // do something with data, like mutate it

  // commit changes
  return exampleRef.update({
    ...data,
    needsProcessing: null /* delete needsProcessing value */
  });
}

const functionsExampleProcessingRef = functions.database.ref("examples/{pushId}/needsProcessing");

export const handleExampleNeedingProcessingOnCreate = functionsExampleProcessingRef.onCreate(handleExampleProcessing);

// this is only needed if you ever intend on writing `needsProcessing = /* some falsy value */`, I recommend just creating and deleting it, then you can use just the above trigger.
export const handleExampleNeedingProcessingOnUpdate = functionsExampleProcessingRef.onUpdate((change, context) => handleExampleProcessing(change.after, context));
```

Comment: Agree - I think we found a modified version for this - I may share in an answer too. The issue as you suggested is that we cannot know the old value in case of an update. Also, the import function may delete some keys which will fire more functions. I will accept the answer though. Please review my answer for any feedback

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [Sam's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66242479) is to use feature flags to determine if a Cloud Function performs its main function. I often have this in my code:

```
exports.onUpload = functions.database
  .ref("/uploads/{uploadId}")
  .onWrite((event) => {
  return ifEnabled("transcribe").then(() => {
    console.log("transcription is enabled: calling Cloud Speech");
    ...
  })
});
```

The `ifEnabled` is a simple helper function that checks (also in Realtime Database) if the feature is enabled:

```
function ifEnabled(feature) {
  console.log("Checking if feature '"+feature+"' is enabled");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    admin.database().ref("/config/features")
      .child(feature)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
          resolve(snapshot.val());
        }
        else {
          reject("No value or 'falsy' value found");
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Most of my usage of this is during talks at conferences, to enable the Cloud Functions at the right time (as a deploy takes a bit longer than we'd like for a demo). But the same approach should work to temporarily disable features during for example data import.

Comment: thank you for helping with this question timely. I am afraid that this still fires the function

Answer (score 0):

Okay, another solution would be

A: Add a new table in firebase like `/triggers-queue` where all CRUD that should fire a background function are added. In this table, we add a key for each table that should have triggers - in our example `/examples` table. Any key that represents a table should also have `/created`, `/updated`, and `/deleted` keys as follows.

```
/examples
.../example-id-1

/triggers-queue
.../examples
....../created
........./example-id
....../updated
........./example-id
............old-value
....../deleted
........./example-id
............old-value
```

Note that the old-value should be added from app (front-end, etc).
We set triggers always onCreate on
`/triggers-queue/examples/created/{exampleID}` (simulate onCreate)

`/triggers-queue/examples/updated/{exampleID}` (simulate onUpdate)

`/triggers-queue/examples/deleted/{exampleID}` (simulate onDelete)

The fired function can know all the necessary info to handle the logic as follows:

- *Operation type*: from the path (either: created, updated, or deleted)
- *key of the object*: from the path
- *current data*: by reading the corresponding table (i.e., `/examples/id`)
- *old data*: from the triggers table

Good Points:

- You can import a huge data to `/examples` table without firing any function as we do not add to the `/triggers-queue`
- you can fanout functions to pass the limit 1000/sec. That is by setting  triggers on (as an example to fanout on-create)
  `/triggers-queue/examples/created0/{exampleID}` and
  `/triggers-queue/examples/created1/{exampleID}`

bad-points:

- more difficult to implement
- need to write more data to firebase (like old-data) from the app.

B- Another way (although not an answer for this) is to move the login in the background function to an HTTP function and call it on every crud ops.